# Question about Embedded 3D file exported to web so it Rotateable

Tags: three.js, blender

I'm more about a visual person, so 3D, 2D stuff
when it comes to something related to code I am clueless

I wondering how would I achieve something like this
https://www.cryptokickers.com/shoes/hermes-shoes/HERMES

You got a web, and you could rotate it freely.

I'm trying to test it using **Wix** for now to achieve something like the link of website above

So far my research that possible to achieve it are

- Using blender,create 3d. export as gLTF
- But I am clueless with the next step

Where to put my gLTF file?
Do I need some html coding?
How is the pipeline to bring my 3D object embedded to web?

Is there anything to do with Three.js? If yes, could anyone point me into some direction
randomly watching youtube regarding webAR, three.js quite gives me headache without a proper pointer

Thank you  to all who read and help out!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially [`How do I ask a good question?`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [`How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: For three.js-specific information, be sure to reference the [docs](https://threejs.org/docs) and the [examples](https://threejs.org/examples)--you can learn a lot by looking at the code for the examples, and cross-referencing the docs. Also, see [Docs: Creating a scene](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Creating-a-scene) for an intro with descriptions on the what/how of how the scene is created and rendered.